# Further golfing this C# code from Scramble words while preserving their outlines

Tags: code-golf, tips

I'll start off by saying I [checked](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/can-i-ask-about-improving-golfing-on-some-code) and [checked again](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1724/38550) that this question should be on topic.

I will also clearly state that this is a [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question about further golfing a certain set of code **not** a challenge.

---

I recently answered the following challenge:  [Scramble words while preserving their outlines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119891/38550):

> It is well known that a text can still be read while the innards of its words have been scrambled, as long as their first and last letters plus their overall outlines remain constant. Given a printable Ascii+Newline text, scramble each word according to these rules:
>
> 1. Scrambling must be (pseudo) random.
> 2. A word is a sequence of the Latin characters, A through Z.
> 3. Only initial letters will ever be uppercase.
> 4. The first and last letters must stay untouched.
> 5. When scrambling, only letters within one of the following groups may exchange places:
>
>    1. `acemnorsuvwxz`
>    2. `bdfhkl`
>    3. `gpqy`
>    4. `it`
>    5. `j` (stays in place)

[My answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120253/38550) is in C# and coming in, currently, at 394 bytes:

```c#
namespace System{using Text.RegularExpressions;using Linq;s=>Regex.Replace(s,@"[A-Za-z](([acemnorsu-xz])|([bdfhkl])|([gpqy])|([it]))*?[a-z]?\b",m=>{var a=m.Value.ToCharArray();for(int i=1,j;++i<6;){var c=m.Groups[i].Captures;var n=c.Cast<Capture>().Select(p=>p.Index-m.Index).ToList();foreach(Capture p in c){a[j=n[new Random().Next(n.Count)]]=p.Value[0];n.Remove(j);}}return new string(a);});}
```

I think there's room for golfing in the Linq statement and `foreach` loop at least.

Can this code be further golfed down?

Comment: Off the bat, `(i|t)` is shorter than `([it])`. And if you order your character classes differently, you can probably replace the really long one with `[a-z]` because all the other letters will have already been covered by earlier groups. I'm also not sure your code works correctly for words containing `j`. As far as I can tell those words wouldn't be matched (instead of just leaving the `j` untouched).

Comment: @MartinEnder It wouldn't have handled the `j` correctly, good spot on that and with the re-ordering the regex is a bit shorter so that helps too! I'm not the best with regex if you hadn't realised...

Comment: Since the input is limited to ASCII, you can also use `\p{L}` for `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: @MartinEnder I'd seen that suggestion on other answers and forgotten about it! Regex is now `\p{L}(([bdfhkl])|([gpqy])|(i|t)|(j)|([a-z]))*?[a-z]?\b`

Comment: If you put the first group before the last one, it can be shortened to `[bdf-l]`, because `gij` have already been taken care of.

Comment: @MartinEnder All that has saved 10 bytes so far: `\p{L}(([gpqy])|(i|t)|(j)|([bdf-l])|([a-z]))*?[a-z]?\b`. Can you add an answer with the improvements so far?

Answer (score 0):

As I am using `linq` in my program, I can change `ToCharArray` to `ToArray` to save 4 bytes.

I can also change the `namespace` around to be either `System.Linq` or `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to save a further 6 bytes by removing the `using` for it:

```c#
namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

As @MartinEnder♦︎ points out in the comments I can save 10 bytes by re-ordering the groups in the regex and changing `[A-Za-z]` to `\p{L}`:

```c#
\p{L}(([gpqy])|(i|t)|(j)|([bdf-l])|([a-z]))*?[a-z]?\b
```

Comment: Oh god that second person really messes with me. Talking about yourself as you? Do you mind if i change it?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Can if you want yeah. It's because I've done a few on SO where it makes more sense to use second person in a self answer. I don't suppose it matters either way though.